# Swapping values in Array using my own swap function on C++

Tags: c++

I was trying to swap values within my array using my own `swapp` function.  The swap function takes in pointers, and I pass my `x` and `y` by reference and a pointer to my array. Then finally swap the values.

In the array below, I am swapping index 0 and 1, however the output is not working.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void swapp(int arr[], int *x,  int *y) {
    int temp = arr[*x];
    *x = arr[*y];
    *y = temp;

}

int main() {
    int w[] = { 1,2,3,4 };

    swapp(w, &w[0], &w[2]);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << w[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

swapping index 0 with index one and was expecting the output 2, 1, 3, 4 but I got 3, 2, 3 4.

Comment: Hint: You should either take pointers to elements **or** an array and indexes. Not both. Are you swapping *elements* or are you swapping *indexes*?

Comment: you treat `x` and `y` as elements and indices. They cannot be both, decide for one

Comment: What's wrong with `std::swap`?

Comment: If you provide pointers to the elements you want to swap, then why do you also provide `int arr[]` to the function? If you want to provide indices for the elements you want to swap, then why do you provide pointers?

Answer (score -2):

What about something like this:

```
void swapp(int *start, int *end)
{
    while (start < end) {
        auto tmp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = tmp;
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
}

int main() {
    int w[] = { 1 };
    auto len = (sizeof(w) / sizeof(w[0]));

    swapp(&w[0], &w[len-1]);

    for (auto i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cout << w[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP reimplemented `std::swap`. You reimplemented `std::reverse`. Thats not what the question asked for. Anyhow you shuold explain what you changed on the code and why.